# Upgrade Rooftop HVAC

Tags: hvac, roof

I am planning a rooftop HVAC upgrade. My current HVAC frame (leg) has cracked one of the 2 x 6 roof rafters that I have repaired with wood glue and anchor screws, so it is good now, but it served as a lesson. The new unit is 100 pounds heavier (about 550), and I need to know load specs on my roof. Here is what I did after the repair. I carefully cut and installed two sister 2 x 6 rafters. One to each of the adjacent rafters on each side of the HVAC frame. Each one is buttered with wood glue, bolted (1/2" bolts) at the top, middle and bottom, with a three inch screw every twelve inches to insure the sister-ed rafters are bonded together. So now I have effectively one 4 x 6 rafter under both sides of the HVAC frame. The rafter span is 13.5 feet and the unit is located 48 inches from the top side of the rafter at the ridge board (hip). Can anyone help estimate the load capacity of this scenario. Either absolute failure or code recommendation or whatever seemed relevant. I just don't want in invest a small fortune just to have it damage the roof and cause problems that I can avoid with some preventative measures before hand.

Comment: The roof pitch is 20 degrees...